# Eigensystem Sort in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica, eigenvector

I'm trying to implement in Mathematica a method for analytical solution of reaction kinetics.

Numerically it is not a problem but in a symbolic form, one have to rearrange by hand columns of EigenVectors in order to get the "right" result.

Please check [www.biokin.com/tools/pdf/Koro11-Kinetics-Maple-Chap2.pdf](http://www.biokin.com/tools/pdf/Koro11-Kinetics-Maple-Chap2.pdf), page 41-44 for example.

I'm using a matrix

```
K={{-k1 - k2, 0, 0, 0}, {k1, 0, 0, 0}, {k2, 0, -k3, k4}, {0, 0, k3, -k4}}
```

as pointed out in example on page 43. `{vals,vect}=Eigensystem[K]` gives a different answer.

As a result my final solution `vect.DiagonalMatix[Exp[vals]].Inverse[vect]` is a mess.

Is there way to Sort the answer when it is in symbolic form? Or how to "force" Mathematica, not to arrange Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting of Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors is entirely arbitrary, the important part is that that you get the right ones together.

The issue with your code is that `vect` is a list of the eigenvectors, which when you use it as a matrix is a matrix whose rows are the eigenvectors, whereas you need a matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors. Use `Transpose` to fix this. Once you've done this, if you simultaneously permute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues nothing changes:

```
randsamp = RandomSample[Range[4]];
vals[[randsamp]]
Transpose@vect[[randsamp]].DiagonalMatrix[Exp[vals[[randsamp]] t]].Inverse[
   Transpose@vect[[randsamp]]] // Simplify
```

Also there is a specific stack exchange site for Mathematica: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com